# Python ffmpeg on Windows

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I had installed ffmpeg in **WIN7 64bit**. When I use 
`os.system("ffmpeg -i      rtsp://218.204.223.237:554/live/1/66251FC11353191F/e7ooqwcfbqjoo80j.sdp -c copy dump.mp4")` in my program by the **PyCharm**,it can also run but I can`t play the **dump.mp4**. I can run the same command in **CMD** or **Python(command line)** and get the **dump.mp4** successfully.Why? How can I solve this problem?Can you help me ? I just use Python not long before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run `python ***.py` in the CMD is OK.Should`t run the program in the PyCharm.Perhaps the environment is differnet.